# Is it possible to set class of an item after it has been declared?

Tags: html, css

I would like to have all my menu items which are common to all the pages on my website in a single header file. The problem lies that I need to define a class for the current menu item so it changes color. I`m using superfish for the menu, here is a very simple mockup...

```
<nav> 
  <ul class="sf-menu">
     <li id="first-li"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
      <li class="current"><a href="page1.php">Page 1</a>
         <ul>
             <li><a href="submenu1.php">Submenu 1</a> </li>
             <li><a href="submenu2.php">Submenu 2</a> 
                 <ul>
                 <li><a href="subsubmenu1.php">SUBSubmenu 1</a> </li>
                 </ul>
             </li>
          </ul>

      </li>
      <li><a href="page2.php">Page 2</a> </li>
       <li><a href="page3.php">Page 3</a></li> 
       <li><a href="page4.php">Page 4</a></li>
   </ul>
 </nav>
```

Is it possible to remove class="current" , move the whole nav to the header file and then only specify the current class on each page?

My actual menu code is much much larger and this is why I do not want it repeated on every page.

Comment: It is really unclear what you want to do and when you want to do it. Is this on the server? Client? What do you mean by move the navigation to the header file?

Comment: Changing the DOM and switching classes, You need Javascript for this.

Comment: @Oded client side, moving the whole <nav></nav> to a header file instead of having it on each page.

Comment: What do you mean to another file? You can't change server side files using client side. Do you mean you want to move it to an include file? That would have to be on the server.

Comment: @Oded yes moving to include file

Comment: What's the problem then? You need to do this on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working exactly how I want by combining a little of all the answers.

First I gave id`s to all the 1st tier menu items, the ones I want highlighted, then on each page I move the current class like so...

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".sf-menu li" ).removeClass("current");
$( "#menu2" ).addClass("current");  
}); 
</script>
```

clean, simple and works without clicking, thanks to all that answered you all helped.

Answer (score 0):

use this in your current page script

Use jquery for the thing..

```
$('.sf-menu li a').click(function() {
        $('.sf-menu li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('current');
    });
```

find the fiddle here..http://jsfiddle.net/VudYx/

Comment: +1 as you had a downvote with no comment.  Just to let the OP know, this answer does use JS and jQuery

Comment: not working, also don't think click function is appropriate, what if user goes directly to a page via url?

Comment: @user2107004 have you checked in the fiddle..use jquery

Comment: yes, seems to work in jfiddle but not really what I`m looking for. Need it to happen on load & I have multiple pages in the same menu item so the current does not work either. I need to specify exactly which li item I need to add the class on every page load.

Comment: Put all this code in your header page..include this header page in all other pages..

Answer (score 0):

Add class="current" to the index.php li in the header and just use the following jQuery code in header.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var curUrl = window.location.pathname;
curUrl=curUrl.replace(/\/$/, "");//support urls with or without trailing slash
$( ".sf-menu li" ).each(function(i) {

if(($(this).children().length > 0) && ($(this).children(":first").attr("href").split('/').pop()==curUrl.split('/').pop()))
{
$( ".sf-menu li" ).removeClass("current");
$(this).addClass("current");
}

});  
})
```

Comment: Edited to support the case when homepage is accessed without using index.php in the url.

Comment: works but how do I make it work for sub menus? My menu has 3 tiers, edited the question... I would need to add the current class only to the first tier of the menu even if I am in sub menu pages...

Comment: then it would be easier for you to do it on server side. Make some variable which identifies the current page then add condition in each li,  <?=($page=="thispage")?'class="current"':'')?>. Even the above can be modified to support your case but you will have to do it yourself. I have done something similar [here](http://www.biketoursdirect.com/packing-for-a-bike-tour") in right navigation menu, take that as example.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'd achieve this using CSS.

If each menu item `<li>` has its own class, and your `<body>` has a unique ID per page, you can style the current item appropriately such that:

```
<li class="navHome">Home</li>
<li class="navAbout">About<li>
```

and your home/about pages have a body tag such that:
`<body id="pgHome">` or `<body id="pgAbout">`

Then you can directly style the current page's menu item:

```
#pgHome .navHome,
#pgAbout .navAbout
{
 // styles to highlight this item
}
```